# write puppet config to clone github repo

Tags: windows, git, puppet, git-clone, rspec-puppet

I've written a Puppet module to install Git on Windows. The Puppet Master is Linux.

Is it possible to write a Puppet manifest to clone a GitHub repo using just puppet resources (i.e. without a script or exec)?

This is a private repo, so  the solution needs to include secure credentials.

Comment: Not sure why you have that limitation. I didn't support windows system, and can only recommend the forge modules for linux: [puppetlabs/vcsrepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo)

Comment: As shown  puppetlabs/vcsrepo actually does work on Windows, it's just not officially supported :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed possible on Windows! You can use the [puppetlabs-vcsrepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) module

[image: Example of it in action]
Screenshot using a Windows 2012R2 machine in Virtualbox, command-line on the left, GUI on the right.

Code I used in the example:

```
vcsrepo { 'C:\foo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo',
}
```

To keep the repository at the latest revision, set ensure to 'latest'.
However, this overwrites any local changes to the repository.

```
vcsrepo { 'C:\foo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo',
}
```

To control what ref, tag, or branch the git repo is on, use the ref parameter:

```
vcsrepo { 'C:\foo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  revision => 'development',
}

vcsrepo { 'C:\foo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  revision => '0c466b8a5a45f6cd7de82c08df2fb4ce1e920a31',
}

vcsrepo { 'C:\foo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  revision => '1.1.2rc1',
}
```

Comment: Hey, what did you use to make that gif?

Comment: thanks Peter but I'm on Windows : Latest version is compatible with:
Puppet Enterprise 3.x
Puppet 3.x
RedHat, Ubuntu, Debian, SLES, Scientific, CentOS, OracleLinux

Comment: Yep, the machine on the left in the screenshot is a Windows 2012R2 server with Puppet installed on it. The version compatibility in the metadata is those platforms that are explicitly supported, it might work on other platforms also (which it does in the case of Windows! :D)

Comment: Peter to what degree does puppetlabs-vcsrepo ensure the repo ?  is it ensuring the repo is always in a usable state ? does it re-clone if entire repo ( or even repo git config files ) are deleted ?  is it checking for changes on a schedule which it then pulls-down ?

Comment: You can see the examples in https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo#usage, but the simple answer is ensure just does a git clone, then wont touch it unless you delete the directory. Latest will always ensure that it's the latest version. The revision parameter lets you point at a specific branch or ref.

Comment: Peter my app will create/checkout a working branch, add/modify a file, stage/commit/push. Will puppetlabs-vcsrepo notice that that current branch is not master and switch it back ?  I don't want that to happen.

Comment: If you choose "ensure=>present" it will only check that the repo exists and has the right endpoint, changes made by your app wont be reverted.

Comment: thanks Peter, could you please verify this is correct line to add to Puppetfile : `mod 'puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo', '1.3.0'`  ?

Comment: Yep, that's the latest release, and the release I tested on the Windows machine

Comment: do you have a solution for securely storing credentials on puppet-server and including in vcsrepo config ?